# How to fast-forward and rewind audio in j2me / blackberry (midp) application?

Tags: blackberry, audio, java-me, midp, cldc

I want to fast-forward and rewind recorded audio in a j2me and Blackberry application.

Is there any sample code available? How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point, read the specification of JSR-135: http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=135

Once you have started a Player object, fast-forward and rewind are done by calling the 3 following methods:

Player.stop();
Player.setMediaTime();
Player.start();

When you need to calculate the value of the parameter you need to pass to setMediaTime(), you will probably need to call

Player.getMediaTime();

Once you get all that, check the blackberry documentation to see if there are any differences between the standard J2ME API and the blackberry APIs in that area.